# How to delete row in UITableView with UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm using UITableView with UISearchBar.
In this case I have two tables and two arrays (All/filtered)
How can I delete a row?
I can set If statment, and delete message from filtered array, but allMsg array still consists it.

Answer (score 0):

use temporary array and insert all filter array data except deleted data from filter array and reload table by using data source from temporary array.